# Code First Many-Many Error (may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have looked at so many questions and tried every solution available but it seems not to work with my specific scenario. I am trying to add a code-first many to many relationship for the below classes and receive the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.AgentPoolAgents_dbo.Agents_Agent_Id' on table
>   'AgentPoolAgents' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Agent

```
    public class Agent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string AgentName { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Available { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<AgentPool> AgentPools { get; set; }

    public Agent()
    {
    }
}
```

AgentPool

```
    public class AgentPool
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Agent pool name")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public virtual string PoolName { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Agent> Agents { get; set; }

    public AgentPool()
    {
    }
}
```

UserId is a foreign key to a UserProfile class to identify the owner of agents and agentpools.
The error appears when running a migration using the update-database package manager console command.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I just pasted your code and did a migration. Everything worked fine, there's probably more entities on your model that interact with Agent, and that's what's creating the circular reference

Answer (score 1):

You don't need every field to be virtual. Not sure what you're trying to achieve by doing this. Use the 'virtual' keyword to eager load navigation properties, e.g. Keep ICollection Agents virtual.

In answer to your question, look at: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382783/entity-framework-code-first-many-to-many-mapping-table).