# EF code first migration - one-to-many to many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have entities User and DiscussionThread and I need to create many-to-many relationship but I forgot to put a ICollection in User entity, so Code First created a one-to-many relationship.

I wonder if there is a way how to migrate this relationship to many-to-many. I tried following things, but nothing helps:

- I added ICollection to User entity
- I added modelBuilder.Entity().HasMany(t => t.NotificationSubscribedUsers).WithMany(u => u.SubscribedThreadNotifications) to configuration
- I tried generate new migration (using Add-Migration), but migration is empty

No DB tables were created/updated and EF still uses a one-to-many relationship...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework code first many-to-many mapping table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382783/entity-framework-code-first-many-to-many-mapping-table)

Comment: Not a duplicate because it doesn't cover migrating from 1:N to N:N.

Comment: Do you have data in this tables? can they be deleted?