# Deleting only one entry from Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

Ok, so i have this problem right now. I have 2 Models like so:

```
public class Contact: BaseModel
    {

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        public string Adress { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstMidName+ " " + LastName;
            }
        }

        public virtual List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Phones> Phones { get; set; }
    }
```

and also:

```
public class Group:BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    }
```

the idea is that many contacts can be in many groups. But here comes my problem. I remove the convention ondeleteCascade with many to many because i had to otherwise my code wouldn`t work.But... how can i delete only one contact... without it cascading and deleting all the groups it`s in and all the contacts that group contains and so on and so forth. That`s my problem i`d love to be able to delete  one contact not a group tho. i do not want the group to be deleted just the contact. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply keep the `cascade delete` option turned `on` for that relationship.

In the `many-to-many` relationship, none of the sides "owns" the other. Instead, the relationship is maintained by a third entity (hidden in your case) called "link" table, so for instance deleting a contact will simple delete the group **links** tied to that contact, not the actual group entities. The same applies when deleting a group.

**EDIT:** While the above applies in general, it turns out that the actual problem is caused by the two `one-to-many` relationships (`User->Contact` and `User->Group`) not mentioned in the question which by default has `cascade delete` turned `on`. Which leads to a classical *multiple cascade paths* issue - when deleting a `User` record, the link table `GroupContact` records can be deleted by either `User->Contact->GroupContact` or `User->Group->GroupContact`, hence is a multiple delete path.

So you have to turn at least one of the `User->Contact`, `User->Group` or `Contact<->Group` relationship `cascade delete` off. Unfortunately that will cause you maintenance problems because you'll not be able to simple the delete one of the entities involved. Since I guess you are not deleting users so often, I would suggest you to turn `User->Group` relationship cascade delete off and manually delete the related `User.Groups` before deleting a `User`. Or put a delete trigger on the `User` table inside the database.

Comment: I can`t .. It gives me an error when i update the database! 
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.GroupContact_dbo.Contact_Contact_ID' on table 'GroupContact' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: That means you have something in common between `Contact` and `Group`. Can you post the `BaseModel` class? Or, looking at the classes, you probably have cascade delete from User to Contact, and User to Group?

Comment: public class BaseModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

    }
It just holds an ID, And the whole idea of the BaseModel is for me to Pass it to the BaseRepository

Comment: That's set by default to `one-to-many` relationships which `User->Contact` and `User->Group` are.

Comment: So you are saying that the fact that My group has a User it creates a problem? But that is a problem since the groups have to be connected to the user since only that user has access to his/her groups. And the user btw contains a List<groups> and a list<COntacts>

Comment: @stefantigro Correct.

Comment: I think i am kind of beggining to understand the problem but i can`t really find the exact solution

Comment: What about The user?

Comment: All you are doing is correct. The problem is caused by limitation of SqlServer which is enforced in EF. Just turn cascade delete off as I suggested (`modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasRequired(e => e.User).WithMany(e => e.Groups).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`. Then, when deleting an user, do first `db.Groups.RemoveRange(db.Groups.Where(g => g.UserId == userId_to_be_deleted));`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about how your data is structured. Why does each contact have to hold a list of all groups? By doing this, each contact in your system holds all information about each other contact, including himself.

This is SQL's way of telling you your data relationship doesn't make sense.

Why not rather have each group hold a list of all contacts in its group?

That's your first option, but if you REALLY need to make this work, probably you want to build a [mapping table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). [Lots of examples of these around.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382783/many-to-many-mapping-table)

Comment: That is an alternative but i`m required to use many-to-many relationship... and besides.. There has to be a way to delete just a single entity? I can write you the sql statement that can do that. Surely entity framework can do the same?

Comment: So i should remove the List<Groups> and List<Contact> ? And then do the mapping table?

Comment: the mapping table does not solve my problem. it still gives an error with the FK