# EF Many to Many cascading delete

Tags: entity-framework

I have an issue.
I have some classes that look like this:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public int CriteriaId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionGroupId { get; set; }

    public QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual Criteria Criteria { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<State> States { get; set; }
}

public class Criteria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<State> States { get; set; }
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CriteriaId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
    public Criteria Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

They have a many to many relationship, so I created this mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
    .HasMany(m => m.States)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => {
        m.MapLeftKey("AnswerId");
        m.MapRightKey("StateId");
        m.ToTable("AnswerStates");
    });
```

When I tried to update my database I get an error about foreign keys.
So I added this line (as a temporary fix):

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

But I need the cascading delete.
I can't seem to figure out why it won't let me have it.
The error I get when trying to include cascading deletes is:

> > Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.AnswerStates_dbo.States_StateId' on table 'AnswerStates' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I hope I have provided enough information. Does anyone know what I can do to allow the cascading delete (I need to be able to delete a **State** or an **Answer** and it to remove the record from **AnswerStates**

Comment: It's not directly seen from the post, but seems like you have some common cascade delete path originating from `Answer.Question` and `State.Criteria`. Could you post the `Question` and `Criteria` models?

Comment: Added them, hopefully that helps

Comment: The multiple cascade path is caused by both `Criteria` and `Answer` having a property `States`, so they both try to cascade delete states. Further, many-to-many is never implemented with cascaded delete. You have to add it manually in the migration, or change the association to "1-n-1", i.e. draw `AnswerStates` as en entity into the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much the same as another question ([Deleting only one entry from Many-to-Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567974/deleting-only-one-entry-from-many-to-many-relationship/36568292#36568292)) I was answering today. Just your case is a bit more complicated.

The multiple cascade path in your case is from `Criteria` to `AnswerStates`. When deleting a `Criteria` record, the `AnswerStates` records can be deleted either by `Criteria->States->AnswerStates` or `Criteria->Questions->Answers->AnswerStates` relationships.

The solution is always one and the same - turn one of the relationships `cascade delete` off and handle deletion either manually or via trigger.

In this particular case, my suggestion is to turn `Criteria->States` cascade delete off:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Criteria>()
    .HasMany(m => m.States)
    .WithRequired(d => d.Criteria)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CriteriaId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

and use something like this before deleting a `Criteria`:

```
db.States.RemoveRange(db.States.Where(s => s.CriteriaId == criteriaId_to_be_removed));
```